# ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'

Tags: python, keras, jupyter

I have a script that runs well on google collab and kaggle, but regarding their memory limitation, I'm now trying to run it on my jupyter notebook in my laptop but then the error message shows.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'
```

It called from the line:

```
from pixellib.tune_bg import alter_bg
```

I alreaddy imported what seems to be required:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation, Concatenate, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, concatenate)
```

And also installed:

```
!pip install pixellib
```

My Specification: 
No GPU 
keras version 2.8.0 
tensorflow version 2.8.0 
Python version '3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]'

IPython          : not installed 
ipykernel        : 6.8.0 
ipywidgets       : not installed

jupyter_client   : 7.1.2 
jupyter_core     : 4.9.1 
jupyter_server   : not installed 
jupyterlab       : not installed 
nbclient         : 0.5.10

Any suggestion please?

Comment: which version of tensorflow and keras are you using?

Comment: print(tf.__version__) = 2.8.0. Should I downgrade?

Comment: Yes try to downgrade it. and also try to import it indivitually then other layers.

Answer (score 9):

Go to Pixellib folder -> semantic -> deeplab.py and replace this line
`from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization`
with this one
`from keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization import BatchNormalization`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are importing BatchNormalization
here:
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation, Concatenate, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, concatenate)`